# HIDManager Wierd CFRunLoop Termination

Tags: objective-c, macos, device-driver, hid

I've created device matching and device removal callbacks, And need to run CFRunLoop to get those callbacks invoked whenever device plugged in and removed.

But the problem is, DeviceMatching callback takes a lot of processing time and depends on device to be attached, So I want to detect if device is removed by running the CFRunLoop for a limited time, and With that the device removal callback happens.

But, It works for 2 times and then it throws exe_bad_access.

```
  IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching( tIOHIDManagerRef, matchingCFDictRef );
  if( matchingCFDictRef ) {
        CFRelease( matchingCFDictRef );
  }
  IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback(tIOHIDManagerRef,
                                                 Handle_DeviceMatchingCallback,NULL);
  IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback(tIOHIDManagerRef, Handle_RemovalCallback, NULL);

  IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop(tIOHIDManagerRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
      CFRunLoopRun();
```

Device Add Callback

```
static void Handle_DeviceMatchingCallback(void* inContext, IOReturn inResult, 
                             void* inSender, IOHIDDeviceRef  inIOHIDDeviceRef) {
      //DO SOME HEAVY PROCESSING

      //NOW WE NEED TO CHECK IF DEVICE IS STILL CONNECTED
     [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]  runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];

      //DO POST PROCESSING

}
```

Device Removal Callback:

```
static void Handle_RemovalCallback( void* inContext,IOReturn  inResult,
                        void*  inSender, IOHIDDeviceRef inIOHIDDeviceRef) {
     //NOW THIS GET's INVOKED, after keeping in run loop

}
```

Following is the code for generating matchingCFDictRef

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef matchDict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    CFNumberRef vendorIDCFNumRef  = CFNumberCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &vendorId );
    CFNumberRef productIDCFNumRef = CFNumberCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &productId );

    CFDictionarySetValue( matchDict, CFSTR( kIOHIDVendorIDKey  ), vendorIDCFNumRef );
    CFDictionarySetValue( matchDict, CFSTR( kIOHIDProductIDKey ), productIDCFNumRef );

    CFRelease( vendorIDCFNumRef );
    CFRelease( productIDCFNumRef );
```

Comment: What line generates the exception? And what's the stack?

Comment: CFRunLoopRun(); ( I also see CFRunLoop calling CFGetTypeID in stack trace)

Comment: The stack contains method of first code block, and then CFRunLoop, and then CFGetTypeID

Answer (score 1):

How do you generate `matchingCFDictRef`? Though normal conventions would suggest that IOHIDManager should retain or copy it, it's possible that it isn't. I would try taking out the `CFRelease` for now and see if that improves things.

The crash in `CFGetTypeID` indicates that it is trying to work with a CF object that has been freed. A few things you can do to try to debug which one it is:

- Turn on [NSZombie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode). It might work, even though this is a CF object (many CF objects are toll free bridged and will still work).
- In the debugger, check the parameter to `CFGetType`. See [Inspecting Obj-C parameters in gdb](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/02/04/inspecting-obj-c-parameters-in-gdb/) for the correct register depending on your processor. (It doesn't matter that this page is for ObjC; you just want the entires related to `arg0`.)

Comment: If I turn on NSZombie, It works but I don't see any log in console or any message in Instruments.

Comment: So that leaves the debugger. Check what the address is of the object being passed to CFGetType and compare it against objects that you know about.

Comment: Please check my other response

Comment: Can you please let me know on how to check the address in the stack trace

Comment: It's not in the stacktrace. You need to check it in the debugger, as noted in the "Inspecting Obj-C parameters in gdb" link above.

Comment: BTW, I only see this problem if I do [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]  runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];,  without it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code for generating matchingCFDictRef

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef matchDict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    CFNumberRef vendorIDCFNumRef  = CFNumberCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &vendorId );
    CFNumberRef productIDCFNumRef = CFNumberCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &productId );

    CFDictionarySetValue( matchDict, CFSTR( kIOHIDVendorIDKey  ), vendorIDCFNumRef );
    CFDictionarySetValue( matchDict, CFSTR( kIOHIDProductIDKey ), productIDCFNumRef );

    CFRelease( vendorIDCFNumRef );
    CFRelease( productIDCFNumRef );
```

Now, I see different stack trace, called from **CFRunLoop**, Though I still see the GetTypeID in the symbols

```
0x00007fff8534407a  <+0023>  jne    0x7fff8534409f <IOHIDDeviceScheduleWithRunLoop+60>
0x00007fff8534407c  <+0025>  mov    0x18(%rdi),%rdi
0x00007fff85344080  <+0029>  mov    (%rdi),%rax
0x00007fff85344083  <+0032>  lea    0x58(%r12),%rsi
0x00007fff85344088  <+0037>  callq  *0x40(%rax)
0x00007fff8534408b  <+0040>  test   %eax,%eax
0x00007fff8534408d  <+0042>  jne    0x7fff85344148 <IOHIDDeviceScheduleWithRunLoop+229>
0x00007fff85344093  <+0048>  cmpq   $0x0,0x58(%r12)
0x00007fff85344099  <+0054>  je     0x7fff85344148 <IOHIDDeviceScheduleWithRunLoop+229>
0x00007fff8534409f  <+0060>  mov    0x58(%r12),%rdi
0x00007fff853440a4  <+0065>  callq  0x7fff85368f36 <dyld_stub_CFGetTypeID>
0x00007fff853440a9  <+0070>  mov    %rax,%rbx
0x00007fff853440ac  <+0073>  callq  0x7fff85369008 <dyld_stub_CFRunLoopSourceGetTypeID>
0x00007fff853440b1  <+0078>  cmp    %rax,%rbx
0x00007fff853440b4  <+0081>  jne    0x7fff853440cc <IOHIDDeviceScheduleWithRunLoop+105>
```

I see that it is breaking at ***0x00007fff85344080  <+0029>  mov    (%rdi),%rax***, for IOHIDDeviceScheduleWithRunLoop ( Please search with 0x00007fff85344080)

With the help of reference document, I see it is the first argument which means tIOHIDManagerRef, which I create IOHIDManagerRef tIOHIDManagerRef = IOHIDManagerCreate( kCFAllocatorDefault, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone );

But, How to see the address of it, from above stack trace ?

Comment: I'll try removing that CFRelease on vendor and Product ID